# Running aosp on uncommon display sizes possible?

Tags: android, android-source

I'm working on a project involving AOSP Android and display recognition. I've successfully built AOSP (13) for the development boards Hikey960 and Dragonboard845, and most monitors work flawlessly when connected via HDMI. However, I encountered an issue with one specific development display that has an uncommon resolution of 780x350.

When I connect this display to either of the development boards, I receive the following error messages:

```
E  getActiveMode failed for display 4621278797924644728: No active mode
A  HWC returned no active modepid-8137
```

I suspect that this error is related to the display's unusual resolution, but I'm not entirely sure. As I'm not well-versed in "display" topics, I'm not sure which parameters are crucial for Android to support these displays.

Could someone please shed some light on what "no active mode" means in this context? The error message appears to originate from "/surfaceflinger/DisplayHardware/HWComposer.cpp." However, before delving into the code without a clear direction, I thought it would be beneficial to seek advice here. Perhaps someone with expertise in this area can provide a helpful hint or guide me in the right direction.

Thank you for your assistance.